# How can I get class Properties values saved in a List of objects and Iterate using a loop

Tags: c#

This Is the class I have

```
public class Income
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int Month1 { get; set; }
        public int Month2 { get; set; }
        public int Month3 { get; set; }
        public int Month4 { get; set; }
        public int Month5 { get; set; } 
        public List<Income> income { get; set; }

    }
```

In the other class

```
List<Income> incomeList = new List<Income>();

//repeat twice
Income obj = new Income();
obj.Month1 = 200;
obj.Month2 = 150;
...
IncomeList.Add(obj);
obj.income = IncomeList;
```

Now I want to retrieve those Months in a loop for each new obj saved in a 
    List.
So far

```
Int[] results = obj.income
    .Select(x=> new 
    {
         x.Month1,
         x.Month2,
         x.Month3,
         x.Month4,
         x.Month5
     })
     .ToArray();
```

This is where I need to add the total months for each unique object.
get The total for All Months1 , Months2 ...

```
double totals[] = new double[5];
 for (int i=0;i<results.length;i++)
 {
     totals[i] += results[i]; // I get the first object reference
     // I want Moth1,Month2 ... to be in an indexed array where 
     // if i want Month1 i would access similar to : results[index];
 }
```

Comment: Not sure I'm 100% clear on what you're trying to do.  But if you want those 5 properties to be in a list, can you simply add a property to that class which returns those property values as a list?

Comment: Don't you want to have `public int[] months = new int[5]` instead of these 5 `int MonthX`?

Comment: @David I will do so

Comment: @ Gariel J the other class represents the data from the db with unique Code that why , thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the following code will project out a list of objects. Each object will have a single property called "Months" which is an `int[]` of the month values.

Does that do what you need?

```
void Main()
{ 

    var incomeList = new List<Income>();
    Income obj = new Income();
    obj.Month1 = 200;
    obj.Month2 = 150;

    incomeList.Add(obj);

    var results = incomeList
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Months = new int[]
            {
                x.Month1,
                x.Month2,
                x.Month3,
                x.Month4,
                x.Month5
            }
        })
     .ToArray();


    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        var testResults = results[i];
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 1: {testResults.Months[0]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 2: {testResults.Months[1]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 3: {testResults.Months[2]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 4: {testResults.Months[3]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 5: {testResults.Months[4]}");
    }
}
```

However, given your comments in the posted code, I think you want to to turn it into a 2-dimensional array. If so, simply project out an `int[]`:

```
void Main()
{ 
    var incomeList = new List<Income>();
    Income obj = new Income();
    obj.Month1 = 200;
    obj.Month2 = 150;

    incomeList.Add(obj);

    int[][] results = incomeList
        .Select(x => new int[]
        {
            x.Month1,
            x.Month2,
            x.Month3,
            x.Month4,
            x.Month5
        })
     .ToArray();


    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        var testResults = results[i];
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 1: {testResults[0]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 2: {testResults[1]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 3: {testResults[2]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 4: {testResults[3]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month 5: {testResults[4]}");
    }
}
```

Comment: int[][] results = incomeList ...  this worked results[objectRef1][index0] retrive 200 . thanks